# How Can I Read The Output Of Modbus Sensor Using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am trying to read [this Keller depth sensor](https://www.kelleramerica.com/product?id=5e2f280c9d8b1060a188c364#) using Modbus with a Raspberry Pi 5. It reads pressure (in bar) and temperature (in Celsius). The water depth can then be calculated using those values. I have got to where I can read registers. Now, because I don't understand Modbus, I don't know what registers I need to read to access the data I want and how to properly read the data. The communication protocol documentation can be found [here](https://www.kelleramerica.com/file-cache/website_component/5e2f280c9d8b1060a188c364/manuals/1625167636569).

These are the communication basics:

```
Mode: RTU Mode (ASCII is not supported)

Coding System: 8–bit binary, hexadecimal 0–9, A–F
Two hexadecimal characters (bytes) contained in each 8–bit field of the message

Bits per Byte: 1 start bit
8 data bits, least significant bit sent first
No parity (default) 1 parity bit: even or odd parity (programmable)
1 stop bit (default) 2 stop bit (programmable) (Class.Group-version 5.21-XX.XX and 5.24-XX.XX)

Error Check Field: 2 Byte Cyclical Redundancy Check (CRC)

Baudrate: programmable 9’600baud (default) or 115’200baud
```

The code I have been using is this:

```
import minimalmodbus

mb_address = 1

sensy_boi = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyACM0',mb_address)

sensy_boi.serial.baudrate = 9600
sensy_boi.serial.bytesize = 8
sensy_boi.serial.parity = minimalmodbus.serial.PARITY_NONE
sensy_boi.serial.stopbits = 1
sensy_boi.serial.timeout  = 0.5
sensy_boi.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
sensy_boi.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
sensy_boi.close_port_after_each_call = True

print(sensy_boi) 

data =sensy_boi.read_registers(0, 2, 3)

print(f"Raw data is {data}")

sensy_boi.serial.close()
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? (based on a quick look it seems OK). Note that some of the data this device returns (e.g. reg 0, section 4.4.1.1 in the manual) is 32 bit floating point (encoded over two registers) so the raw data may not be what you expect ([this](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/) can help). Personally I'd suggest using something like [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll) to experiment before writing your own code.

Comment: Most of the registers I have read have returned 65535 which isn't correct. I have found a couple of registers have varied results but most of them are 65535. This made me wonder if I was making the request correctly. I have tried mbpoll using `mbpoll -a 1 -t 3 -r 40007 -c 2 -o 3 -b 9600 -P none /dev/ttyACM0` but I get an illegal function error. I don't know exactly how registers work. If the hex code for the register is 0x0006 does that mean I need to read 40007 or 6 or 7? I know there's something of that sort you have to do but I don't understand it entirely.

Comment: Register numbers are confusing - see "When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" in [this article](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html). Try `mbpoll -a 1 -t 4:float -0 -r 2 -c 1 -o 3 -b 9600 -P none /dev/ttyACM0` (should give you P1 - [args are a little confusing](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll/issues/64))

Comment: So I have done quite a bit of testing and with `mbpoll -a 1 -t 4:float -0 -r 2 -c 1 -o 3 -b 9600 -P none /dev/ttyACM0` I get  answers like `-1.4606e-09`. The responses vary a lot which should not be the case. If the values vary slightly would be okay but the responses should be close to the same as the sensor is currently in the open air.

Comment: I also get `-nan` if I read the 6th register which should be the temperature.

Comment: OK - try adding `-B` (Big Endian word order). If that does not have the expected result then get the raw values - `mbpoll -a 1 -t 4:hex -0 -r 0 -c 12 -o 3 -b 9600 -P none /dev/ttyACM0`. The manual does say "Inactive Channel returns NaN".

Answer (score 1):

As @Brits mentioned, you can use tools like mbpoll for a quick test.

Here I will recommend another useful python tool [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll), which helps not only on quick troubleshooting but also further data acquisition using the same config file.

Create a config file `keller-sensor.csv` for generic Keller sensors with the following content,

```
device,testdev01,1,,
poll,holding_register,0,12,BE_BE
ref,Calculated_value,0,float32,r
ref,Pressure_of_sensor1,2,float32,r
ref,Pressure_of_sensor2,4,float32,r
ref,Temperature,6,float32,r
ref,Temperature_of_sensor1,8,float32,r
ref,Temperature_of_sensor2,10,float32,r
```

> ***Note***: Only show partial registers in section 4.4.1.1 Process Value Read Range (0x000x) for demo

Follow [guide](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) to install modpoll and run the following command,

```
modpoll --rtu /dev/ttyACM0 --rtu-baud 9600 --config keller-sensor.csv
```

You shall be able to view the **device readings** in **realtime**.

Furthermore, you can deploy [modpoll](https://github.com/gavinying/modpoll) program in production using the same config file, refer to the official [document](https://helloysd.gitlab.io/modpoll/usage.html#Named%20Arguments) for more options.

### Revised config file for older device models

According to keller manual's section 4.3.2, there are limits of maximal number of registers read in one cycle for some older models.

- up to 2 registers for earlier versions than Class.Group-version 5.20-10.40

```
device,testdev01,1,,
poll,holding_register,2,2,BE_BE
ref,Pressure_of_sensor1,2,float32,r
```

- up to 4 registers for versions Class.Group-version 5.20-10.40 and later

```
device,testdev01,1,,
poll,holding_register,2,4,BE_BE
ref,Pressure_of_sensor1,2,float32,r
ref,Pressure_of_sensor2,4,float32,r
```

Comment: `2024-02-09 22:49:00,582 | I | modpoll.main |  ====== modpoll polling at rate:5.0s, actual:5.0s ======
2024-02-09 22:49:00,609 | E | modpoll.modbus_task | Reading device:testdev01, FuncCode:3, Start_address:0, Size:12... ERROR
===== references from device: testdev01 =====
Failed to poll device: testdev01
Done.` This is the only output I get. I can get some output with mbpoll but it is not lining up with what it should be giving me.

Comment: Can you run the following command and share the output? `modpoll --rtu /dev/ttyACM0 --rtu-baud 9600 --config keller-sensor.csv -1 --loglevel DEBUG`, which will run in debug mode.

Comment: I get [this output](https://github.com/caseyKoehn/animated-umbrella/blob/main/modpoll-output.txt). I uploaded it to Github because it's too long for a comment.

Comment: accoridng to section 4.3.2 of keller manual, the response `0x1 0x83 0x2` means "Illegal data address", which i think is due to the limit of "maximal number of registers read in one cycle" (described in the same section), you might want to adjust your config according to your actual device model version, revised my answer above.